# Attempt to toggle switch to authorize requests using OAuth 2.0 in Google APIS Explorer returns 500 error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Note, this isn't an in code problem, this is error when I as developer attempted to configure a service in a browser using Google APIs Explorer.

The service is [Google Analytics Reports API v4](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/analyticsreporting/v4/) and when I go to toggle "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:" it throws a dialog to Select OAuth 2.0 scopes: where I check the checkbox for the readonly version 'https:://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' and the press the button marked Authorize.  Whereupon a new dialog says "500.  That's an error.  There was an error,  Please try again alter.  That's all we know."

And I have tried again after an interval.

UPDATE: Tried again just now, still not working.  Tried suggestion below.  Also, tried on my IPad (as opposed to Windows 10 PC) to see if device specific.

Comment: Have you tried using the API Explorer here? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

Comment: @ScottMcC : that didn't work, thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: I tried your link and it works for me, can you try and do it in an chrome incognito window with no previous cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your link and it works for me, can you try and do it in an chrome incognito window with no previous cookies?

This looks like mixture some bad old cookies might be causing an error here

Comment: chrome incognito revealed some sort of stake cookie issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is a server error. Most of the time this means you are not doing anything wrong. Perhaps this is a temporary issue with the API Explorer. As how [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) suggested, you can try to do it in chrome incognito window or a guest session. During my experience, sometimes I found this behavior. If you are still getting the error, I suggest to try the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see if you also get the same error there. If you do, then try with another user, but always using an incognito or guest session. If you still do, then try using another network. I hope it helps!